# python/scapy - packets sent but unable to receive them

Tags: python, networking, scapy, arp

I'm trying to do an ARP scan and print MAC addresses of reachable IP addresses.

Here's the part of my code where I use ARP ping method :

```
ans, unans = srp(Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(pdst="192.168.1.0/24"),timeout=2)
ans.summary(lambda s,r: r.sprintf("%Ether.src% %ARP.psrc%"))
```

I put a random IP address for the example.

Here's my response, I really don't understand why my packets are not received :

```
Begin emission:
Finished sending 1 packets.
Received 0 packets, got 0 answers, remaining 1 packets
```

Comment: Does Wireshark show anything noteworthy?

Comment: The code works for me though. Make sure the network and mask are correct. Maybe also try increasing the timeout.

Comment: Oh also, **always**, **always**, **always** provide an argument for the `iface` parameter when using a send/receive function! Scapy will try to guess the interface otherwise, and it often guesses wrong.

Comment: I specified the iface argument, and it does work now. Thank you very much !

Comment: Np. Ya, never skip that. That was the source of nearly all my pain when first learning scapy.

Comment: Just came by to say that I spent so much time and finally your answer about `iface` saved me, thank you so much!